# VS2017- Solution Configuration won't apply changes - Does not build the selected configuration

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution with one project and 3 solution configurations:

1. Debug
2. Release
3. Staging

When I for example choose "Release" in the quick menu toolbar to change the active solution configuration and Hit F5 I expect the solution to be compiled in Release mode, but whoooo it's still debug (Output window). Ok, let's go to the configuration settings and clear it up.

But the IDE will not apply my changes...? What's wrong here?
When I go to `solution -> properties -> All Configurations` I expected all my configurations to be visible that I have configured. As I have only one project, I expect "Release", "Debug" and "Staging (added by me)" to be present.
But they are all set to debug...

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you open the "Configuration Manager" via the Build entry.

[image]

It opens the same "Configuration Manager" when going the route: Right-click Solution --> Properties --> Configuration Manager.

Now you can choose the Active solution configuration for example "Release" and check if the projects configuration is also set to Release, if not change it.

[image]

Click Close and rebuild your solution. Now it should build the chosen configuration. You have to repeat these steps for every configuration: Debug|Test|Staging ...etc.

**This time it will remember the settings!**
When going solution- -> properties it will not, at least in my case.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Make sure your solution file has a configuration set for the release mode you want.

To do this, right-click the solution in Visual Studio and choose Properties. Then use the "Configuration Manager..." button. In the dialog box that appears, for the project you want to add a configuration for, choose the drop down in the Configuration column.

(2) Right-click your project file in Visual Studio and choose Properties. Select the 'Build' tab. Make sure the 'Configuration' drop down menu has the build configuration you want to use and that you have a corresponding 'Conditional compilation symbols:' entry set that matches. See screen shot below.

[image]

(3) In your code behind file (.cs for C#). You'll should see the

```
#if VALIDATION
// Your code when building for VALIDATION
#elif PRODUCTION
// Your code when building for PRODUCTION
#endif
```

By changing the drop down at the top of the screen, each of the conditions you've coded for should be enabled/disabled (visually by shading of the text) based on the configuration selected.

[image]